# confused about a simple formula to move player to mouse position

Tags: c++, math

I encountered a simple formula on the internet to move a player to mouse position based on calculating the distance between characters X position and Mouse X position and dividing it by the distance between the two entities like below

```
//the below statement moves the player to the left towards the mouse pointer

    if(player.position.x > Mouse_Position_X)
       player.setPosition(player.position.x  - ( ( player.position.x - Mouse_Position_X)/distance * 2.0f ));
    ...
    ..
    .
// similar statements for other three checks to move player to right, top and bottom
// distance value is found out by a getDistance function which calculates the distance between two entites(player and mouse pointer in this case)
```

I would like to know what the above formula does as compared to a simple formula like below
which also moves the player to the left.

```
if(player.position.x > Mouse_Position_X)
   player.setPosition(player.position.x  - 2.0f);
```

Why would we subtract the players current position with the mouse position and divide it by their distance?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first case moves the player to the mouse position.  It is the same as player.setPosition(Mouse_Position_X).  The second moves it left by 2 units.  Quite strange that there is no vertical movement.

Answer (score 0):

The first formula also depends on some variable `distance` which is not defined. It seems to move the player's position somewhat in the direction of the mouse coordinate.